# Conditional sideloaded data in ActiveRecord::Serializer(based on controller actions)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-4

I don't have so much experience in rails and building an application.i was trying to building an API using ActiveModel::Serializers.

What is the best way to side load data conditionally for particular event action?

Do I have to do it by sending query params with each call or i can set includes: true only for specific action or any another suggestion?

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index, :show]
  before_filter :locate_collection, :only => :index
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:create, :index, :show]
  before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /events
  def index
    if params.has_key?("mode") and params[:mode] == "owned"
      own_event
    else
#       @events = Event.all
      render json: @events
     end
  end

  # GET /events/1
  def show
    render json: @event
  end

  # GET /events/new
  def new
    @event = Event.new
  end

  # GET /events/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /events
  # POST /events.json
  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
    @event.creator_user_id = current_user.id
    if @event.save
      render json: @event
    else
      render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /events/1
  # PATCH/PUT /events/1.json
  def update
    if @event.update(event_params)
      render json: @event
    else
      render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /events/1
  # DELETE /events/1.json
  def destroy
    aa = @event.destroy
    render json: aa
  end 

     def own_event
       @events = Event.where(creator_user_id: current_user.id)
      if @events.count > 0
        render json: @events
      else
        render json:   []
      end
#     else
#         render json: {error: 1, message: "Events not found."}, status: 404
#     end
  end

  def locate_collection
    if (params.has_key?("filter"))
      @events = EventPolicy::Scope.new(current_user, Event).resolve(filtering_params)
#       @event_orders = EventOrder.filter(filtering_params)
    else
      @events = policy_scope(Event)
    end 
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_event
      @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.


  def filtering_params
    params.slice(:event_type_id)
  end

end

    **My Event serializer**
It includes data for multiple association listed below. i don't want to show all the data with event call.
    class EventSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :event_name, :event_start_date, :event_end_date, :creator_user_id, :event_proposal_id, :daily_start_time, :daily_start_time, :payment_category, :total_capacity, :contact_email, :description, :graced_by, :contact_details, :video_url, :demand_draft_instructions, :status, :cannonical_event_id, :website, :event_type_id, :additional_details, :event_start_time, :event_end_time, :committee_id

  embed :ids
  has_one :address, include: true
  has_many :tickets, include: true
  has_many :event_cost_estimations, include: true
  has_many :event_seating_category_associations, include: true
  has_many :event_awarenesses, include: true
  has_one  :pandal_detail, include: true
  has_one  :bhandara_detail, include: true
  has_many :event_tax_type_associations, include: true
  has_many :event_team_details, include: true
  has_one :event_type, include: true
#   has_many :event_registration_center_associations, include: true
  has_many :registration_centers, include: true
#   has_many :event_registrations, include: true
  has_many :event_orders, include: true
  has_one :venue_type
end

 In event serializer i have includes :true for sideloaded data and I want to show sideloaded data(includes: true) of registration_centers and tickets only for index action.
```

What can I do for this?

Comment: You should sideloaded things for specific action .. or can call a method from model that will do that inside that model

Comment: I'm not sure what sideloading means. If you clarify I may be able to help. Do you mean that you want to include some data for `index`, but much more data for `show`?

Comment: @ChuckVose u can go through these links for what i mean from sideloading.  

http://www.valentinmihov.com/2015/01/17/rails-plus-emberjs-plus-active-model-serializers-plus-her/
 http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_sideloaded-relationships

Comment: I don't have time for a proper response today so I'll leave a comment. With AMS you often have to create multiple serializers for different purposes. For us, we have an IndexSerializer and a ShowSerializer which show different info. The IndexSerializer only has an id and some sorting stuff, but the ShowSerializer has _all_ the details about an object.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are using AMS version 0.8.x,

You can create a base_serializer.rb like this and extend the same.

```rb
class BaseSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  def include_associations!
    if @options[:embed]
      embed = @options[:embed].split(',').map!(&:to_sym)
      embed.each do |assoc|
        include! assoc if _associations.keys.include?(assoc)
      end
    end
  end
end

class EventSerializer < BaseSerializer
```

and the index method in EventsController can be written as

```rb
# GET /events?embed=registration_centers,tickets
  def index
    if params.has_key?("mode") and params[:mode] == "owned"
      own_event
    else
#       @events = Event.all
      render json: @events, embed: params[:embed]
     end
  end
```

I just showed you that, the associations that are needed, can be added in url params. You can think of some smart way to send the params such that you don't need to add them in the url request.